# Perl Program to append user info from HTML form to a CSV file

Tags: jquery, html, perl, csv, cgi

I am required to append user info from an HTML form to a CSV file in Perl.
If the username exists, an error HTML page should be displayed linking the user back to the home page.

So far my code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use CGI;
use strict;
my $username = param('username');
my $name = param('name');
my $password = param('password);


$file = 'Members.csv'
open(PTR, '<<$file') || fatalError("Unable to open members file");

# if user name exists link to HTML page
else
seek(PTR, 0, 2);
print PTR $username;
print PTR $name;
print PTR $password;


close(PTR);

sub FatalError{
print "$_[0]";
exit;
}
```

This is just a skeleton version of the code.
Could anyone give me any pointers and help?

Comment: What kind of open mode is `<<`?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.32/lib/Text/CSV.pm) module. For example, you could do:

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new();
open (my $fh, ">>", $fn) or die "Could not open '$fn' for writing: $!\n";
$csv->combine ($username,$name,$password);
my $line = $csv->string ();
print $fh $line . "\n";
close( $fh);
```